# Draw two lines with different x-axis with d3.js

Tags: d3.js

The problem is:
e.g.
Line 1:
  x: [1,3,4,5,6], y: [3,4,5,6,7]
Line 2:
  x: [2,4,6,7,8], y: [1,2,3,4,5]

As the x-axis are different, how can i draw these two lines in the same figure in D3.js

Comment: is google turned off in your area?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you have 2 scales for the x axis? do you want to draw the line based in one of these scales?